# Read the output of a kubeflow pipeline programatically

Tags: python, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I run pipelines on Kubeflow with a python command like:

```py
client.create_run_from_pipeline_func(pipeline_function, arguments=params_dict[name], run_name=name)
```

It creates a job on Kubeflow pipelines and I would like to be able to access the information about the different steps of the pipeline with a python API.

```py
job.get({step_name}).get_custom_properties({property_name})
```

I can do that by opening the run in Kubeflow and looking at the custom properties of the step of the pipeline I am interested into but I would like to automate this process. Do you know if it is possible to do that with a python API?

Comment: Maybe not directly an answer, but you can use ZenML (https://github.com/zenml-io/zenml) with the ZenML orchestrator (https://github.com/zenml-io/zenml/tree/main/examples/kubeflow) exactly for that. You can easily create a simple pipeline, run it on Kubeflow, and then use the post-execution workflow (https://docs.zenml.io/guides/index/post-execution-workflow) to fetch pipelines, runs, steps , and their output directly :-)

Comment: what property you are expecting exactly? if it's artifacts/metricx, you can get via the api: (https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/reference/api/kubeflow-pipeline-api-spec/#operation--apis-v1beta1-runs--run_id--nodes--node_id--artifacts--artifact_name-:read-get) and (https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/reference/api/kubeflow-pipeline-api-spec/#/definitions/apiRun)

Answer (score 1):

I used this class to extract the parameters from a kubeflow run:

```py
import json
from typing import Dict
from typing import List

from kfp_server_api.models.api_run_detail import ApiRunDetail


class PipelineResult:

    DATASET_PATH_NAME = "data-load-features-DATA_SET_PATH"

    def __init__(self, run_description: ApiRunDetail):
        self._run_description = run_description

    @property
    def workflow_manifest(self) -> dict:
        return json.loads(self._run_description.pipeline_runtime.workflow_manifest)

    @property
    def status(self) -> str:
        return self.workflow_manifest["status"]["phase"]

    @property
    def params(self) -> List[Dict]:
        params_list = []
        for k, v in self.workflow_manifest["status"]["nodes"].items():

            for params in v.get("inputs", {}).get("parameters", []):
                params_list.append({"node_name": k, **params})
        return params_list

    def get_param(self, param_name: str):
        for el in self.params:
            if el["name"] == param_name:
                return el["value"]

    @property
    def training_set_path(self):
        return self.get_param(self.DATASET_PATH_NAME)

    @property
    def run_name(self):
        return self.workflow_manifest["metadata"]["annotations"]["pipelines.kubeflow.org/run_name"]

    def as_dict(self):
        return {
            "status": self.status,
            "training_set_path": self.training_set_path,
            "run_name": self.run_name,
        }


client = kfp.Client()
api_response = client.list_runs(namespace='...', sort_by='created_at desc', page_size=30)
runs_descriptions = [client.get_run(run.id) for run in api_response.runs]
runs = pd.DataFrame([PipelineResult(el).as_dict() for el in runs_descriptions])
```